# single query that defines 2 tables has same row

Tags: sql

query 1

```
(select count(*) from CALENDAR)
```

it returns 15

query 2

```
(select value from PARAMETER where name = 'PLAN_HORIZON')
```

it returns 15 too only when my programs runs without error. if error occurs, 
it returns 10 or other values.

this↓ is wrong sql, but i want a single query which returns True or False.

```
select if (query1 == query2)
```

How can I define 2 sql has same result in a query?

Comment: If an error is raised, the result is undefined. (Unpredictable.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following SQL statement returns 0 or 1. It runs with SQL Server

SELECT CASE WHEN (select count(*) from CALENDAR) = (select value from PARAMETER where name = 'PLAN_HORIZON') THEN 1 ELSE 0 END

Answer (score 0):

Something like this:

```
select count(*) = 0 
from (
  select count(*)
  from calendar
  except
  select value 
  from parameter 
  where name = 'PLAN_HORIZON'
) t
```

You didn't specify your DBMS, but the above is standard SQL.

Answer (score 0):

Try this query !

```
SELECT 
   CASE
      WHEN (select count(*) from CALENDAR) = (select value from PARAMETER 
                                             where name = 'PLAN_HORIZON')
                 THEN  true
                 ELSE  false
   END ;
```